# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare PHPUnit\Framework\assertArrayHasKey()

Tags: php, phpunit

I need help with this error when try to run phpunit tests in VS code terminal at address: `D:\xampp\htdocs\coscProj>`

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare PHPUnit\Framework\assertArrayHasKey() (previously declared in phar://D:/xampp/php/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Framework/Assert/Functions.php:80) in D:\xampp\htdocs\coscProj\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Assert\Functions.php on line 79
```

As I tried to install phpunit with multiple ways, I am not sure is that the cause of this error or not.

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you that your function is already defined. This usually happens when a file is included/required several times, or the function with the same name is declared in several times. You can wrap [function_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) around your function definition, like

```
if (!function_exists("somefunction")) {
    function somefunction() {}
}
```

But that might be a naive approach. You will first need to make sure that you do not require the same thing several times. If only a single function is duplicated, then you can add the logic above. `require_once` and `include_once` are keywords that spring to mind when this kind of issue happens.